# caching headers from PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, browser-cache, http-caching

In PHP, by default no cache related headers are sent.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Nov 2010 11:02:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.9-2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9-2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 26
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Now, since by default it does not say anything about caching, can it result in say example.com/index.php getting cached in some situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In general, [every successful response may be cached](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.4) unless there are some [constrains](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9):

> Unless specifically constrained by a cache-control ([section 14.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)) directive, a caching system MAY always store a successful response (see [section 13.8](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec13.8)) as a cache entry, MAY return it without validation if it is fresh, and MAY return it after successful validation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, usually the browser will cache certain files by default (usually images and css) if no rules have been setup on the server-side (see [browser cache](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/basics/what-is-browser-cache-definition.php)).

You can set up cache-control headers to control this, or disable it completely using:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

See example #2 in [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and read the note below it.

Answer (score 1):

> can it result in say example.com/index.php getting cached in some situations?

It shouldn't, however there's a lot of implementations out there (particularly on mobile devices / mobile proxies) which don't behave correctly in this regard.

There's also also a lot of bad information about caching - the 'Pragma: no-cache' is [meaningless](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1945/rfc1945.txt) when sent from a server.

To prevent caching:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

When all else fails - [check the manual](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)